Why my edit method don't work in ASP.NET Core
I had a EditEmployee method in AdminController. When I submit the edit form it display the error 404. It seem that the method don't recognize the EmployeeId I bind but I can't figure out
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditEmployee(int id, [Bind("EmployeeId,Name,Email,Password,RoleId,ShopId")] Employee employee)
{
    if (id != employee.EmployeeId)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Update(employee);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!_context.Employees.Any(e => e.EmployeeId == employee.EmployeeId))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
    foreach (var error in errors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage);
    }

    ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(_context.Roles, "RoleId", "RoleName", employee.RoleId);
    ViewBag.ShopId = new SelectList(_context.RetailShops, "ShopId", "Address", employee.ShopId);
    return View(employee);
}

and this is my view:
@model Nexus.Models.Employee
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="EditEmployee" asp-controller="Admin" method="post">
            <div class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Email"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Password"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Role</label>
                <select asp-for="RoleId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RoleId"></select>
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="RoleId"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Shop address</label>
                <select asp-for="ShopId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ShopId"></select>
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="ShopId"></span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

I also tried another approach using IFormCollection, but it didn't work either:
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditEmployee(int id, IFormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        var employee = await _context.Employees.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeId == id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        employee.EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(collection["EmployeeId"]);
        employee.Name = collection["Name"];
        employee.Email = collection["Email"];
        employee.Password = collection["Password"];
        employee.RoleId = Convert.ToInt32(collection["RoleId"]);
        employee.ShopId = Convert.ToInt32(collection["ShopId"]);
        _context.Update(employee);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!_context.Employees.Any(e => e.EmployeeId == id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
        return View();
    }
}

In both cases, the EditEmployee method does not seem to update the employee details correctly, and I am not sure why. The ModelState is invalid, but I cannot determine what is causing it.
Could someone please help me understand what I might be doing wrong? Any suggestions or improvements would be greatly appreciated.
I'm new to ASP.NET Core, thank you so much.

Have you checked, what value you are getting in the controller and which one doesn't matched? If the model binding doesn't match, it would always be false.

In this line, employee.EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(collection["EmployeeId"]); you need this line, you should update other property by the ID not the ID itself.

Also , due to the EmployeeId not being included as a hidden field in the form. Without it, the EmployeeId value won't be posted back to the server, resulting in a mismatch between the id parameter and the EmployeeId property of the Employee object. This can cause the 404 error you're seeing.

You would need to add this line <input type="hidden" asp-for="EmployeeId" /> within your Edit view inside from element.

Thank you so much, I add  and I changed the EditEmployee method to use IFormCollection and retrieve the Employee properties from the collection. This helps update other properties without editing the EmployeeId

I have also given you the updated code which you could test. Make sure you have replaced them correctly within your project.

If you want to do something like this then get it to pick the id from the route and then pass in the model, it's much easier.  The you should really have a DTO(Data Transfer Object) for security, so you are not interacting directly with the entities or people can potentially play around., But ignoring the DTO part, this should work for you.
[HttpPost("{id:int}", Name = nameof(EditEmployee))]
public async Task EditEmployee([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Employee employeeModel)


In both cases, the EditEmployee method does not seem to update the
employee details correctly, and I am not sure why. The ModelState is
invalid, but I cannot determine what is causing it

Based on your shared code snippet, you are getting 404 and your Employee informatin not updating due to the absense of Employee.EmployeeId within your edit form.
Because when you would post edit form your controller expecting Employee.EmployeeId which has not been passed from your from post reuqest, So your model state become false.
In order to fix that, you should inlcude following code  with your edit form.
 <input type="hidden" asp-for="EmployeeId" />

Updated Code should be:
View:
@model Nexus.Models.Employee

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="EditEmployee" asp-controller="Admin" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="EmployeeId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Employee.Name"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Employee.Email"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Employee.Password"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Role</label>
                <select asp-for="RoleId" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.RoleList"></select>
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Employee.RoleId"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Shop address</label>
                <select asp-for="ShopId" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.ShopList"></select>
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Employee.ShopId"></span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

Controller:
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditEmployee([Bind("EmployeeId,Name,Email,Password,RoleId,ShopId")] Employee employee)
{
    var existingEmployee = _context.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeId == employee.EmployeeId);
    if (existingEmployee == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        existingEmployee.Name = employee.Name;
        existingEmployee.Email = employee.Email;
        existingEmployee.Password = employee.Password;
        existingEmployee.RoleId = employee.RoleId;
        existingEmployee.ShopId = employee.ShopId;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    var viewModel = new EmployeeIndexViewModel
    {
        Employee = employee,
        RoleList = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Admin" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "User" }
    },
        ShopList = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Shop 1" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Shop 2" }
    }
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}

Output:




Note: I have tested the scenario with the class object but if you are using IFormCollection then feel free to change the property at your controller.

Glad to assist you on this.
